# Why js file is not picked from local browser cache?

Tags: jquery, apache, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess, browser-cache

I'm analyzing loading issue of website.
[image]

Website avaliblity matrix is mentioned below; on further analysis I found that bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js are taking lot of time to respond.
[image]

Can you please suggest how to reduce bootstrap and jquery js loading time? 
I've already enabled caching via .htaccess (on apache).

Comment: Loading it from CDN, same issue?

Comment: You're loading it from cache. Reply is 304 not modified. Are you hammering your web server to check load capabilities? 6 seconds just to reply 304 definitively indicates a problem somewhere

Comment: @ClaudioRedi ; i didn't get meaning of "Are you hammering your web server to check load capabilities?" can you please elaborate?

Comment: @A.Wolff; i've not tried it loading it from CDN; i'm trying to get root cause of this loading issue.

Comment: Forget about that, you should focus on checking why it takes 6 seconds to reply 304, that's not normal.

Comment: let me check .htaccess; any other place where i should check?

Comment: If you try to navigate that single file on a browser tab, does it also takes 6 seconds to load?

Comment: No, Single file is not taking 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

After removing code mentioned below from htaccess; 6sec loading time is gone

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```